# while os.system(command) is running display tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I verify if a new update is available and if it's true I execute a Windows command

```
query =  "COPY /Y myfile mydirectory"
```

And I want, when it's copying the file, a tkinter window appears and disappears after copy. Also, I want to close the program, delete it, and run the new version.

I tried this:

```py
    if version < float(new_version):
        query = "COPY /Y myfile mydirectory"
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry('300x120')
        root.title('Mise à jour en cours')
        pb = ttk.Progressbar(
            root,
            orient='horizontal',
            mode='indeterminate',
            length=280
        )
        pb.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=40)
        while os.system(query):
            pb.start()
            root.mainloop()
        root.quit()
        query= file_path + "\\" + file
        os.startfile(query)
        exit()
```

Comment: Does your code not work?  Also, could you fix the quotation marks in the `query =` line in your code?

Comment: it works but the tkinter window is not displayed during the copy

Comment: Would you mind editing your post and adding that information?

Comment: You put a `root.mainloop()` in *each* loop. The `mainloop` should generally be started once and then left to run normally (a looping structure in it would involve a function call that calls itself with `.after` after each run). This isn't going to match well; `os.system` is a blocking call, and event loops don't like blocking calls (that don't return control to the event loop while they're blocking). I'd suggest learning to write a true standalone `tkinter` GUI first, then look at integrating file operations later; this wouldn't work even if file ops weren't involved.

Comment: Side-note: There is *no* reason to use `os.system` here. [`shutil.copy` would do the work](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) from within Python, avoiding the creation of a process (or processes; not sure if `COPY` is implemented as a separate process or not), and as of 3.8 (when they tuned it to use per-platform optimized copying) it should be just as fast, if not faster, than delegating to an external process, with better error handling when things go wrong to boot (`os.system` will return an `int`, `shutil.copy` will raise useful exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

`while expr` runs `expr` again and again (and then the indented block) until it returns a "falsey" value.   You are apparently looking for `subprocess.Popen` which lets you run a process in parallel with your Python code; `os.system` will block while the (implicit) subprocess runs, and only then pass control back to your Python code.